# How to read binary column from MySQL/MariaDB to pandas's dataframe?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, mariadb

I am inserting some binary data into `MariaDB` binary column via python.
Following 3 steps are working as expected:

1) Prepare binary data using  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mariadb-dyncol
2) Write data into `pandas DataFrame`
3) Insert `DataFrame` into `MariaDB` table using `mysql.connector` and SQL

**Example:**

```
SQL="INSERT INTO T(id, binarydata) VALUES (%(id)s, %(binarydata)s)”  
data_list=[{ id': 0, '**binarydata**': '\x04\x0f\x002\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00 \x00\x06\x00@\x00\t\x00`\x00\x0c\x00\x80\x00\x0f\x0’}]  
cursor.executemany(SQL, data_list)
```

Here is the problem.  I need to read the inserted data from database, put it into panda’s `DataFrame`, do some manipulation on non-binary columns and write `DataFrame` back to database.

**Issue: I do not know how to correctly push the binary column from `MariaDB` into `pandas DataFrame`.**

I tried to use `HEX()` : `SELECT id, HEX(binarydata) FROM T`

But binary data in dataframe  looks different from data which I initially wrote at steps 1)-3)

Compare  following `data_list` which I got using `HEX()` with `data_list` above:

```
data_list=[{ id': 0, '**binarydata**': u'040F00320000000000030020000600400009..'}]
```

The difference is: binarydata now has prefix `u'` and all `\x` gone.

As a result the following statement

```
cursor.executemany(SQL, data_list)
```

leads to error:

> `'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 24: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: If you select with `HEX()` on the way out, you need to use `UNHEX()` on the way back in.

Comment: Isn't `u'...'` for Unicode?  That would _not_ work.  If you can get the hex, then building (somehow in Panda)  `INSERT ... VALUES (..., UNHEX('040F00320000...'), ...);` is probably the best way to go.